# VBA PowerPoint Run-time error '-2147467259' (80004005): Presentation.Close: Failed

Tags: excel, vba, com, powerpoint

I have a macro which is running from Excel. This macro opens PowerPoint slides, performs some work, and then closes them. The problem I am having is the following:

[image: error]

This error message appears seemingly randomly throughout the course of the macro's runtime. This error is not guardable with `On Error GoTo Label` and it seems that it is time dependent (based on some race condition), as at a later stage, again seemingly randomly, the line will run without issue.

The specific code which causes this error is as follows:

```
myPresentation.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things I tested:

```
myPresentation.saved=true
myPresentation.Close
```

Which didn't fix the issue

```
myPresentation.saved=true
myPresentation.windows(1).activate
myPresentation.Close
```

Also didn't work. In the end the most stable solution I have come across is the following:

```
'This function is implemented as a fix for an issue where VBA reports "Presentation.Close: Failed"
'@param pres as Object<PowerPoint.Presentation> - The presentation to close.
'@docs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78156015/vba-powerpoint-run-time-error-2147467259-80004005-presentation-close-fail/78156016#78156016
Public Sub ClosePresentation(ByVal pres As Object)
  pres.windows(1).Activate
  While Not pres.Saved
    pres.Saved = True
  Wend
  stdWindow.CreateFromApplication(pres.Application).Quit
End Sub
```

This utilises the library [stdWindow](https://github.com/sancarn/stdVBA/blob/master/src/stdWindow.cls) - which is an open source library I maintain. Ultimately this sense the close message to the window indirectly (via the Windows API) which seems to be more stable, as I suppose this is exactly how users usually close windows.

It is important to note that setting saved appears to have some race condition, hence the loop.